# PostgreSQL using XID as unique entry in a table

Tags: postgresql, unique, database-schema, postgresql-9.0

I couldn't find how to set a `xid` (transaction ID type) column to be unique in a table. It complains about class method missing for btree and I have no clue how to get around it.

This is using PostgreSQL 9.0.

Couldn't find any similar question in these forums or on the internet. :-(

Comment: I'm very curious why one would do this, it basically would error if you tried to insert/update more than one row in the table per transaction. When would that be a useful property to have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that there is no `<>` operator defined for data type `xid` (among others). Try:

```
SELECT '123'::xid <> '123'::xid
```

Fails.
You can circumvent this limitation by adding a unique index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_xid_col_uni_idx
ON tbl (cast(cast(xid_col AS text) AS int));
```